# Crash when using URL for swapping images

Tags: iphone

```
@implementation SlideShowViewController
- (id)init
{
    NSString *temp = [NSString alloc];
    [temp stringwithString:@"http://www.inetwallpaper.com/homescreenhero/sunsets/wall009.jpg"];
    temp=[(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                              nil,
                                                              (CFStringRef)temp,                     
                                                              NULL,
                                                              NULL,
                                                              kCFStringEncodingUTF8)
          autorelease];
    NSData *dato = [NSData alloc];
    dato=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil])
    {
        NSArray * images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageWithData:dato],[UIImage imageWithData:dato],  [UIImage imageWithData:dato], [UIImage imageWithData:dato], [UIImage imageWithData:dato], nil];

        self.view = [[[SlideShowView alloc] initWithImages:images] autorelease];
    }

    return self;
}
```

I used the following code to load images from the server and view it as that of a photo album

But when the code is run it gets crashed 
the error message in console is as follows

> 2011-06-24 23:54:01.837
>   SlideShow[13654:207] ***
>   -[NSPlaceholderString stringwithString:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x49117e0
>   2011-06-24 23:54:01.839
>   SlideShow[13654:207]**  Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '** -[NSPlaceholderString
>   stringwithString:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x49117e0'
>   2011-06-24 23:54:01.840
>   SlideShow[13654:207] Stack: (
>       42178640,
>       43336492,
>       42187355,
>       41649782,
>       41646578,
>       12567,
>       7791,
>       2906510,
>       2910543,
>       2936126,
>       2917623,
>       2949592,
>       51171708,
>       41457820,
>       41453736,
>       2908705 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

it works if the URLS are replaced by the images 
could any one help  me
I'm a beginner so its hard for me to find it out

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call an `NSString` class method with an instance (an incorrectly created instance at that) here

```
NSString *temp = [NSString alloc];
    [temp stringwithString:@"http://www.inetwallpaper.com/homescreenhero/sunsets/wall009.jpg"];
```

Change to

```
NSString *temp = @"http://www.inetwallpaper.com/homescreenhero/sunsets/wall009.jpg";
```

*EDIT:*

You are doing several things wrong like calling `alloc` on things and then setting them to something else. (*temp and *data) when you `alloc` something it should always be followed with a call to `init` or `initXXXX`. Next you do not even need those `alloc` calls because you are setting the pointer to something else on the line right beneath it which causes a memory leak.

This is all you need

```
NSData *dato = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp]];
```

Then you are creating a bunch of images with the same data object. You are also blocking the calling thread while you are downloading the image which should done later probably around time of `viewDidLoad` asynchronously.

The init function of the view controller is not the place for setting the view. Implement loadView and the system will call it when it is needed to minimize the applications memory footprint.